# How to specify a python script with opt parser as mapper in Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, optparse

How do I specify a python script which as opt parser (and accepts multiple arguments ) as a mapper in Hadoop Streaming ??

For example ,

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper myPythonScript.py \
    -reducer /bin/wc \
    -file myPythonScript.py
```

This the normal command to execute python script using hadoop streaming. How to mention if the myPythonScript.py has opt parser. For eg.

```
python myPythonscript.py -g --inputfile=Inputfilename --output=Ouputfilename -r
```

How do I specify this as mapper ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper "python myPythonscript.py -g --inputfile=Inputfilename --output=Ouputfilename -r" \
    -reducer /bin/wc \
    -file myPythonScript.py
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: @Zulu just use complete command as option's value. that's not complicated